# How to get all text between [CODE][/CODE]?

Tags: python, python-re

I have text with tags [CODE]something here[/CODE].
How can I take only part between this tags, using re module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) function we can use a regular expression with a capture group which will return a list of all the matches.

```py
import re

regex = r"\[CODE\](.+?)\[\/CODE\]"

test_str = "[CODE]Noob[/CODE] Nb[CODE]something here[/CODE]"

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Dont work with "[CODE]Noob[/CODE] Nb[CODE]something here[/CODE]"

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `re.findall`.